# In Visual Studio, how do i view my table records?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

so I have created an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web project. I added a SQL server Database to my App_data folder. I created a model for a table in the DB then created a controller for the model. I can debug the project and add an entry into the table.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(GalleryTypeDB gallerytypedb)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.GalleryTypes.Add(gallerytypedb);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(gallerytypedb);
}
```

I can view the table entries in my browser

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

But when I go to `~/App_Data/Database.mdf` , then right click the table and hit show table data the table is empty. How do I view my table's data without writing a query to view it?

Comment: What do you mean "without querying it"? Either through Entity Framework, or ADO.NET, or even via SQL Server Management Studio, you still "query" the table to see its content

Comment: I want to view the table entries in visual studio instead of writing code to show it in my browser or in console. I don't understand why my table is empty when i hit show table data in the Database Explorer

Comment: why don't you try Sql Server Management Studio Express? Its easy to use

Comment: An empty table is an empty table. Put something in the table to make it non-empty. (Make sure the transaction that performed the insert committed correctly and the table being viewed is the correct table.)

Comment: if you don't write on your db there is another db specified in web.config

Comment: He just wants the integrated table viewer in VS.

Comment: @Aniket I downloaded sql management studio and can see my tables populated. I followed Ofiris' advice and now i can view the table data in visual studio. I'm not sure what the mdf file is in my App_Data and why it has the same name as the DB i'm using but w/e, I deleted it and now everything is fine

Comment: @leppie okay, I'll make sure not to thank anyone ahead of time

Comment: @user2285163 what you on about?

Comment: @leppie my question was edited by you two days ago. The only change i see is that the thank you at the end of my question is gone

Comment: @user2285163: If you look at the revision history, you will see I only edited the tags.

Comment: @leppie oh you removed Ofiris' tag! John Saunders removed my 'Thanks!'. Okay, learning pretty quickly how this forum works/responds to questions.

Comment: @leppie, this question is right about `Visual Studio`, see my answer, would you mind if I bring the tag back ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`View` -> `Server Explorer` -> Right click on `Data Conenctions` -> `Add Connection`

And then you can see the data, straight from Visual Studio.

You can also use `Tools` -> `Connect to Database...` which will give you the same connection wizard.

Once connected, you can expand the Data Connection and see the tables, right click on a table and then `Show Table Data`

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b4be09b(v=vs.90).aspx) for more information.

Comment: I thought i already added the connection. There was a mdf file sitting in my App_Data folder with the same name as my DB. After following your directions i can now right click the table and view the entries

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but from what I can understand seem that you are using the default db,  Entity Framework will default to using  LocalDB. By default, the Entity Framework looks for a connection string named the same as the object context class. Have a look to your web.config,

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication2-20141230111314;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication2-20141230111314.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

then have a look to your `ApplicationDbContext`

```
ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
```